# How to convert a string to a variable name in R

Tags: r, dplyr

To access a certain column in a data frame we use `$`, so `data$variable` gives us the column with the column name `variable`. Now suppose I have a string variable `var` called `"variable"`, how do I access the column using `var` instead of `variable`? Saying `data$var` returns `NULL`. I can't use `data[[var]]` either because I need to do a `filter(data, var %in% variable)`. This cannot be fixed by filter_.

Comment: @Andrew Taylor See my edit

Comment: Based on edit OP isn't asking about base but rather about `dplyr`. See the [dplyr vignette on nonstandard evaluation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html). And I'm sure we can find a more appropriate dupe.

Answer (score 0):

Use `data[, var]` for a vector of `data$variable` or `data[var]` for data.frame containing the one column `variable`